# Filtration and detection of dull text from mechanical displays with CV2 python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I've got a little problem with getting the contours of images of this type for filtering and making the 7 seg text inside more readable but I've managed to get some quite good looking filtering with shadow filters and canny but can't get past that because the ROI is quite dull and empty here are the examples:

[image: Normal_Image]

[image: Shadow_removal]

[image: Canny_50_100]

[image: CNT_IMG]

Here is the code I've been working on with some help of people on this forum and a little note I'm still considered a complete beginner.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import subprocess
#import numpy as np

import os #for now used to delete files and empty foders

imgAddr = 'ADisplay2.jpg'
#imgAddr = 'example1.jpg'

# Read image and search for contours.
img = cv2.imread(imgAddr)

cv2.imshow('Test_Img', img)

rgb_planes = cv2.split(img)

result_planes = []
result_norm_planes = []
for plane in rgb_planes:
    dilated_img = cv2.dilate(plane, np.ones((7,7), np.uint8))
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(plane, bg_img)
  #  norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    result_planes.append(diff_img)
 #   result_norm_planes.append(norm_img)

unShadowImg = cv2.merge(result_planes)
#unShadowImgNorm = cv2.merge(result_norm_planes)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(unShadowImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Image_gray', gray)


cannyImg = cv2.Canny(unShadowImg, 50, 110)
cv2.imshow('Current_canny', cannyImg)

_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('Image_tresh', threshold)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cannyImg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cntImg = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Image_tresh_after_fndCnt', cntImg)
cv2.imwrite('cnt_image.png', cntImg)


# Create first mask used for rotation.
mask = np.ones(img.shape, np.uint8)*255

# Draw contours on the mask with size and ratio of borders for threshold.
for cnt in contours:
    size = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 10000 > size > 500 and w*2.5 > h:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Connect neighbour contours and select the biggest one (text).
kernel = np.ones((50,50),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
gray_op = cv2.cvtColor(opening, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold_op = cv2.threshold(gray_op, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours_op, hierarchy_op = cv2.findContours(threshold_op, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours_op, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Create rotated rectangle to get the angle of rotation and the 4 points of the rectangle.
_, _, angle = rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
(h,w) = img.shape[:2]
(center) = (w//2,h//2)

# Rotate the image.
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (int(w),int(h)), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

# Create bounding box for rotated text (use old points of rotated rectangle).
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
a, b, c, d = box = np.int0(box)
bound =[]
bound.append(a)
bound.append(b)
bound.append(c)
bound.append(d)
bound = np.array(bound)
(x1, y1) = (bound[:,0].min(), bound[:,1].min())
(x2, y2) = (bound[:,0].max(), bound[:,1].max())
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

# Crop the image and create new mask for the final image.
rotated = rotated[y1:y2, x1:x2]
mask_final = np.ones(rotated.shape, np.uint8)*255

# Remove noise from the final image.
gray_r = cv2.cvtColor(rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold_r = cv2.threshold(gray_r, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_r,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
    size = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if size < 500:
        cv2.drawContours(threshold_r, [cnt], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Invert black and white.
final_image = cv2.bitwise_not(threshold_r)

final_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
    final_image,
                 20,
                 20,
                 20,
                 20,
                 cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                 value=255
              )


# Display results.
cv2.imshow('final', final_image)
cv2.imwrite('FinalImg.jpg', final_image)
cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)



im = Image.open('FinalImg.jpg')
txtStr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('FinalImg.jpg'))

print("OCR output:")
print(txtStr)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code.

Comment: Yeah sorry thee I was in the middle of doing that but then my laptop suddenly shutdown...